# Google, people api, how can I create a contact in a group

Tags: vba, contacts, google-people-api

With people.createContact I can easily create a contact in myContacts.

But how do I create a contact in a special group ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the contact with the method -  [people.createContact](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact), as you are probably already doing.

### All you have to change is to specify a membership:

```
"memberships": [
    {
      "contactGroupMembership": {
        "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/PASTE_HERE_THE_NAME_OF_THE_GROUP"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Have a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22emailAddresses%22%3A%5B%7B%22value%22%3A%22foobar%40gmail.com%22%7D%5D%2C%22names%22%3A%5B%7B%22givenName%22%3A%22foobar%22%7D%5D%2C%22memberships%22%3A%5B%7B%22contactGroupMembership%22%3A%7B%22contactGroupResourceName%22%3A%22contactGroups%2Ffamily%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D) sample.

Comment: Thx. As I suspected, there are no longer any independent groups in Google, only identifiers (labels, pointers). If I create a contact under a label and then remove this label from the contact, the contact still exists (in myContacts). A question about this, what about the groups Famlily, Coworkers, Starred etc.?

Comment: I did not want to know whether the system groups can be deleted, but what they are there for. They don't appear anywhere.

Comment: This question deviates a bit from your original question, but [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact-group#issystemgroup) you can find information what the purpose of system groups is.