# Add tag for a google contact with People API

Tags: google-people-api

I'm creating a contact with google People API, but I can't figure out how to "tag" that contact with an existing tag of my account.
If anyone knows, will help me a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google, people api, how can I create a contact in a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000605/google-people-api-how-can-i-create-a-contact-in-a-group)

Comment: By ```tag``` do you mean label as described in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60002343/12835757 ?